Build a Query that return changes on Supervisors
I have the following records:



EMPLID

EFFDT
SUPERVISOR_ID




**0100018
LINE_MANAGER
2021-04-01
0075474**


0100018
LINE_MANAGER
2021-10-01
0075474


0100018
LINE_MANAGER
2022-04-01
0075474


**0100018
LINE_MANAGER
2022-05-01
0104352**


**0100018
LINE_MANAGER
2022-09-28
0029581**


**0100018
LINE_MANAGER
2023-01-24
0104352**


0100018
LINE_MANAGER
2023-04-01
0104352


0100018
LINE_MANAGER
2024-04-01
0104352


0100018
LINE_MANAGER
2024-06-01
0104352



I want a query to only show up the changes on SUPERVISOR_ID only (Min EFFDT)
Expected result:



EMPLID

EFFDT
SUPERVISOR_ID




0100018
LINE_MANAGER
2021-04-01
0075474


0100018
LINE_MANAGER
2022-05-01
0104352


0100018
LINE_MANAGER
2022-09-28
0029581


0100018
LINE_MANAGER
2023-01-24
0104352




Have you tried anything, for us to look at, or any research?   select  t.EMPLID, t.EFFDT, t.SUPERVISOR_ID from  YourTable as t group by t.EMPLID, t.EFFDT, t.SUPERVISOR_ID having count(distinct t.SUPERVISOR_ID)>1

This record is the result of a Query:

What kind of database do you have? And what is the name of the second column?

with numbered as 
(
    select *, 
       row_number() over (partition by emplid, supervisor_id order by effdt) rn
    from MyTable
)
select *
from numbered
where rn = 1

